# unable to ssh from one server to another

Tags: ssh

I have 2 servers server A and server B. I am able to ssh to both the servers from my local laptop and from a third server say server C.

But I am unable to ssh into server B from server A and vice versa. I am getting error

```
ssh: connect to host serverA port 22: No route to host
```

Also, ping is not working from within the 2 servers on each other. But ping works from my local and from a third server `server c`. I am unable to figure out the exact cause.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to send data between two machines on a network, those machines need to know how to reach each other. You can imagine that (on a very high level) like driving instructions: "If you want to get from A to B, go five miles ahead, then turn left, then ...". On a more technical level, those instructions look more like "You are A. If you want to send data to B, hand the data over to X. If you want to send data to C, hand the data over to Y. If you want to send data to D, ...".

That principle is called "routing", and the ways for a system to get data to some destination are called "routes". And that's exactly what your servers are complaining in the error message: "No route to host". That basically means "I'm A and you want me to send data to B, but I have *no* clue how to find B on the network."

So the problem is with your basic network setup. We don't know how your network is set up, and giving you a basic course in networking is well beyond the scope of this site. But I hope I could give you a pointer what to read up on :)

Comment: I have less knowledge on networking. Servers A and B are the production servers and these are purchased from Hetzner. I am able to ping and SSH to these servers from my local computer and from other hetzner servers. But SSH and pings do not work from server A to server B and from server B to server A. How do I actually troubleshoot the issue. Can you please help

Comment: @user11549576 As I said, you need to tell A where to find B and B where to find A. Depending on which of Hetzner's products you purchased, you might be entitled to support from them. That's probably your best bet - or to hire somebody that actually knows what they're doing (no offense). To operate servers that can be basically accessed (and attacked) from all over the planet with "less knowledge on networking" isn't necessarily a good idea.